# Creating a custom device for Swing/AWT to draw to

Tags: java, swing, awt, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded linux device that requires custom java code to draw to the screen. I was wondering if there was any way to create a custom adapter that can update the display based off our drawing code. I have done some digging and haven't found any information as to how Devices are implemented or plugged into Swing/AWT. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to go beyond what Swing/AWT would typically call an adapter and create the bridge yourself to the graphics device using JNI (Java Native Interface).  Have a look at this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_AWT_Native_Interface) which describes the JNI aspects of Javas AWT layer - there are links in that page to details of [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) and [Swing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Swings/AWT) which are fairly low-level.  Hopefully this will put you on the right track.